# Control AWS EC2 Access with AWS Cognito (or not) on IOS

Tags: ios, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

I am having a bit of a hard time understand how can an IAM role be used to limit access to a Amazon EC2 instances.

I am currently looking into Cognito, and I was wondering if it could help me. I want to restrict the access of my EC2 instances (with that I mean contacting the Django Server on there) to only a specific group of people, with dynamic ips. So IP restriction is not an option.

If a user gets authenticated with Cognito and gets temporary credentials, and therefore assumes a specific IAM Role, I want him to be able to talk to that EC2-Django server from within my iOS app. If a request to the server doesn't have the IAM, I want Amazon to automatically block it. Is that possible or I have to do that server side?

Comment: Would you please clarify what kind of access of your EC2 instance you want to restrict? With IAM role, you can limit what actions, e.g. start instance, describe instances, etc, to be performed on certain EC2 resources. You can also control what other AWS resources an EC2 instance can access. But if you run a web service on an EC2 instance, and you want to limit who can talk to the web service, I am afraid that your have to build your own authentication logic inside the web service.

Comment: I was talking about accessing the web service yes... I though that somehow if the IAM Role was passed in the header (or whatever) it could be used to grant access to the instance or not. So an IAM Role on a EC2 instance is solely for start, stop etc..? So I have to turn around on the web service authentication, correct?

Comment: @abisson The roles on the EC2 instance are for allowing you to make calls to other AWS services from within the EC2 instance (see the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for more info). Unfortunately there is currently no way for developers to validate AWS credentials inside of their own APIs so you would need to implement your own authentication/authorization scheme.